# Why is "Membership.GetUser(strUser)" returning nothing?

Tags: vb.net

In the following code strUser gets set correctly on line 3.

However user returns a value of Nothing after line 4 executes.

```
Dim strUser As String

Dim user As MembershipUser

strUser = gvUsers.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text

user = Membership.GetUser(strUser)
```

This code is being used to change the password of another user.

I can find lots of references to code which is for the logged in user but nothing else.

Anyone got any ideas.

Many thanks
Amanda

Comment: it depends on where that code is, you gave no context.  `User` *looks like* a local variable (`Dim`) so when that procedure ends it goes out of scope; or maybe `Membership.GetUser` cant find/create the User.  But I am guessing.

Comment: What is the value of `strUser`?  (Not what do you *assume* it is, but when you debug this and stop on that line at runtime what *is* the value?)  Is there a user by that username?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. The UserName and the LoweredUserName were out of sync thus Membership.GetUser could not find the user based on UserName even though it existed.